# What are the "whole numbers"?

Tags: definition

Just recently, I attempted to answer a question involving "[whole numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_number)", but discovered that my long-held assumption (that they're the same as the integers), is not universal.

[In fact, it seems I owe a retraction for whenever I've snickered as a result of people claiming there are no "whole number" solutions to $a^n+b^n=c^n$ when $n>2$.]

> **Question**: When it comes to the "whole numbers", who uses which definition?

I'm thinking geographically.  E.g., since I've always equated whole numbers and integers, perhaps it's an Australian thing (or perhaps it's a "me" thing).

> **Question**: Are there any rules-of-thumb as to who uses what definition?

This matters, because when I'm teaching, I sometimes say "whole numbers" while meaning "integers", and expect others to arrive at the same conclusions as me.

Comment: In my middle school and high school, the whole numbers were defined as the positive integers.

Comment: In Argentina we call whole numbers (numeros enteros) to $n \in \Bbb N \wedge n>0$. Also, why the downvote folks?

Comment: I think that Alex Becker’s experience is very common in the U.S. I may have run into a few people who were taught in grade school to include $0$, but that seems to be less common. I would **NEVER** use the term in a post-secondary setting.

Comment: In India, where I did my schooling, natural numbers meant $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ whereas whole numbers meant $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_number) claims that "whole numbers" can refer to the integers, or the nonnegative integers, or the strictly positive integers. A hidden comment gives a few examples of each usage, which I reproduce below:

Whole number as nonnegative integer:

- Bourbaki, N. [Elements of Mathematics: Theory of Sets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540225250). Paris: Hermann, 1968.
- Halmos, P. R. [Naive Set Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387900926). New York: Springer-Verlag, 1974.
- The Math Forum, in explaining real numbers, describes "whole number" as ["0, 1, 2, 3, ..."](https://web.archive.org/web/20170903053242/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57052.html).

Whole number as positive integer:

- The Math Forum, in explaining perfect numbers, describes whole number as ["an integer greater than zero"](https://web.archive.org/web/20171231211238/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.perfect.html).
- Eric W. Weisstein. "Whole Number." From [MathWorld—A Wolfram Web Resource](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WholeNumber.html).
  (Weisstein's primary definition is as positive integer. However, he acknowledges other definitions of whole number, and is the source of the reference to Bourbaki and Halmos above.)

Whole number as integer:

- Alan F. Beardon, Professor in Complex Analysis at the University of Cambridge: ["of course a whole number can be negative..."](https://nrich.maths.org/1321)
- The [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0395825172), 4th edition, includes all three possibilities as definitions of whole number.
- Webster's Third New International Dictionary (Unabridged) has the following entry: "whole number n : INTEGER".

Answer (score 5):

From Wikipedia, you have that

> **Whole number** is a term with inconsistent definitions by different authors. All distinguish whole numbers from fractions and numbers with fractional parts.
>
> Whole numbers may refer to:
>
> 1. Natural numbers in sense (1, 2, 3, ...) — the *positive* integers
> 2. Natural numbers in sense (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) — the *non-negative* integers
> 3. *All* integers (..., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...)

So it seems it is rather not good to use such terminology and rather stick to the more descriptive positive/negative/non-negative integers, naturals, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Almost nobody uses the terminology "whole numbers." Usually, people refer to {0, 1, 2, ...} as the natural numbers (and sometimes they don't include 0). In general, whatever text you're using will provide a definition and that will be consistent within the text but not necessarily outside it.

This is the case with many mathematical definition--internal consistency within texts, but no guarantee of universal adoption. Generally, however, the definitions of a given concept is similar enough across texts that the same methods of proof apply regardless.

Comment: The first sentence isn’t really true: the term is quite common in grade school.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Indeed. Even more to contrast them with *fractional* numbers, when *integer* can't really convey this.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Why not just say positive integers?

Comment: @Pacerier Those are the natural numbers. I don't follow.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I mean why not just say "integers above zero" instead of saying an ambiguous "whole numbers"?

Comment: @Pacerier Because for a kid "whole" makes more sense, it conveys the idea that we can think of $4$ or $1$ as a whole entity, such as 4 cakes, 1 cake, while we use fractions to convey the partitioned whole.