# How to define mathematically the integer part of an average?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

Scenario: Suppose I have three numbers: `1`, `3` and `4`. The average of the three numbers are `2.67` (to `2` decimal places). It many real-world applications, there is the need to consider only the "whole number", that is, the integer part, hence the value `2` only.
Question: How do I define using **mathematical expression** this particular issue, that is, consider only the whole number result of the average expression?
Thank you.

Comment: casting to int?

Comment: Mathematics has the floor (and ceiling) operations, using "hooked" parentheses. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions . You'll need to take into account whether your average is positive or negative to use those operations.

Comment: I am looking for a "mathematical expression", describing that only the "integer part" of the result is being considered.

Comment: But the wikipedia link I gave shows how you can define truncation as well; applying that to average, you'd get something like \sgn(1/n \Sigma x_i) \lfloor | 1/n Sigma x_i | \rfloor  .

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  The floor and ceiling functions cause a number to become an integer, but you aren't liking that answer.  You can say `floor(8/3)=2`, but you can't say `8/3 ∈ N`, because that's false.  `∈ N` is a statement, not a conversion of one number to another.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the symbol to refer to the set of whole numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151037/what-is-the-symbol-to-refer-to-the-set-of-whole-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You can define the integral part using Greatest integer function(represented as |_ _|).

So, greatest integer(2.67) =  |_ 2.67 _| = 2.

And, in almost all of the programming languages there exists methods/functions defined in mathematical libraries to achieve the same.

In Java, you can achieve the same using `double floor(double d)` method.

Ex :- Math.floor(2.67) = 2.0 and then you can convert it into int using down-casting OR down promotion.

```
int res = (int)(Math.floor(2.67));
```

As mentioned by Evert, if you're performing operations with negative average, then  you need to use smallest-integer function(ceil function).

```
int res = (int)(Math.ceil(2.67));
```

So, your code would be :-

```
if(avg>=0)
Math.floor(avg);
else
Math.ceil(avg);
```

Comment: What about negative results?

Comment: Not what I am looking for.

Comment: For that OP can have an if-else condition. Wait, I'm editing that in my answer.

Comment: @Evert-Please check now...

Comment: @george24-What do you want? A mathematical expression??

Answer (score 1):

Integers in Java don't use remainders, so if you were to add all values together and divide by `N` (the number of values), you should arrive at the greatest whole number.

This is in no way a highly accurate method of doing it, but it is definitely a fast solution that *"works"*.

```
int a, b, c;
a = 1; b = 3; c = 4;
System.out.println((a + b + c) / 3); //Equals 2 [replace 3 with N]
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily Java.

Comment: My bad. How do other languages compute Integers differently?

Comment: Java, C, C++, and many others use integer division and this would work fine.  Python (version 3+) and Javascript use floating point division.

Comment: That's probably why I'm over-assuming, I'm not a scripting guy (yet) :P @Teepeemm

Answer (score 1):

$$
\text{sgn} \left( \frac{1}{n} \Sigma x_i \right) \left\lfloor \left\lvert \frac{1}{n} \Sigma x_i \right\rvert \right\rfloor
$$

Answer (score -1):

Mathematically, 
     `Avg(n1,n2,...nm) = p/q` for lowest values (no more divisible) for all p belongs to natural number and q =1.

Comment: Mathematically, that will only happen if the average is already an integer, making this question (whatever it is) moot.

Comment: @Teepeee...Sorry but looks you don't aware about algos, it was just an psuedo. If you didn't understand, you may ask.

Comment: @eorge24 , pls. accept answer if it solves your problem. Do  you need programming solution , pseudo, algo. You may clarify if the answers are still acceptable.

Comment: `Avg(1,3,4) = 8/3` is lowest values, with `p=8` and `q=3≠1`.  What part of your algorithm am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Teepeemm, Oh that is not I am trying to explain. For "mathematical expression that is, consider only the whole number" , your 8/3 is not giving the whole number per the rule. To get and confirm if the whole number is achieved , the expression can be formulated. With the provided example, the output will not be fully whole number and we need a so called to trunk or floor or ceil the value. So it is a first step.if it fails/not fulfilled then user has confirmed that he need to use special functions (or he need alto) will be cleared after first step.

Comment: @Teepeemm-It seems the author of this answer is unaware of all other answers posted here and himself written a crap and bewildering solution. You may better downvote and flag rather than make this `intelligent` person understand...